# An error occurred (ThrottlingException) when calling the GetDeployment operation (reached max retries: 4): Rate exceeded

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, bitbucket-pipelines, bitbucket-aws-code-deploy

With an increase in the number of Deployment Groups in AWS CodeDeploy, BitBucket Pipelines are starting to fail more often.

> **PIPELINE FAILED...**

```
+ python ./_scripts/codedeploy_deploy.py
Failed to deploy application revision.
An error occurred (ThrottlingException) when calling the GetDeployment operation (reached max retries: 4): Rate exceeded
```

Is there any way to increase the value before rate limit or reduce the chance of occurrence?

**AWS FORUM POST:** https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=892511

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to increase the rate limit, as this is dynamically provisioned by the AWS API.

> **AWS SUPPORT:**
>
> This issue is not related to any concurrent deployment or any other resource related limit. This is a throttling issue, which cannot be changed.
>
> Multiple API calls initiated at the same time gets throttled at our endpoints. The limit for each endpoint is varies and is dynamic, therefore it is not documented anywhere.
>
> In this case, there are multiple calls for 'GetDeployment' API simultaneously hence the calls are getting throttled.
>
> In such scenarios we recommend to implement error retries and exponential backoff between retries, so that the API calls are not simultaneous.
>
> You can check the below link which explains how to implement it in our Code.
>   - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/api-retries.html

I was able to implement an exponential back off to reduce the rate at which we are trying to get the deployment status and also increase the number of retries before deployment failure.

Make sure you are using the latest version of BOTO3 *(boto3-1.9.108 botocore-1.12.108)* which supports this new config system.

**BOTO3 RETRY CONFIG:** https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/882#issuecomment-338846339

**FORK:** https://bitbucket.org/DJRavine/aws-codedeploy-bitbucket-pipelines-python/src/master/ 
**GIST:** https://gist.github.com/djravine/5007e2a7f726cebe14ea51c7ee54bf5d

> **PIPELINE SUCCESSFUL...**

```
+ python ./_scripts/codedeploy_deploy.py
Deployment Created (Exponential back off 30s)
Deployment InProgress (Exponential back off 60s)
Deployment Succeeded
```

**NOTE:** I will update this post with more information as I revise the usage based on our deployments.

Comment: Great! you asked question then immediately answered, now comment and accept it.

Comment: I think there is a new 2 day limit before I can accept the answer

Comment: @AdanRehtla Hi, can you pls confirm the config is only to increase the rate limit. Also the aws link you provided says exponential back off is in built into the SDK, so why do we need to explicitly impement it again? Thanks.

Comment: Also you seem to be linearly backing off and not exponentially backing off, would you agree?              deploymentDelay = (deploymentCounter * DEPLOYMENT_BACKOFF_SECS) https://gist.github.com/djravine/5007e2a7f726cebe14ea51c7ee54bf5d#file-codedeploy_deploy-py-L106

Comment: @Gadam 1. There is no way to increase the rate limit, this boto3 config is to increase the max retries. The SDK does have basic backing off, but if you are hitting hard limits (I was deploying to multiple pipelines to multiple projects at the same time, which hit the AWS hard limit) you will need to extend this yourself.
2. You are correct, but to most people (and AWS) that is an acceptable exponential back off strategy using an incrementally increasing delay.

Comment: How can we overcome this issue in `bash` or `groovy` scripts? Its lucky that boto3 has this exception handler but unfortunately my scripts are not in python :(

Comment: You mentioned implementing exponential backoff - isn't exponential backoff already implemented in boto3? At least that's what I've read in their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @adan rehtla, there is no way of manually increasing the rate limit yourself. Following are the findings after raising a support ticket for AWS:

1. Amazon EMR throttles the following API requests for each AWS account on a per-Region basis
2. EMR uses a token bucket scheme for throttling. So if the user makes the same call, on average, at the same rate or less than this refill rate, you should be okay
3. For each API, there is an account-level credit bucket with an upper limit. When you make an API call, one credit is taken from the bucket. At the same time, the bucket is being refilled with a fixed refill rate. If you are making API calls at the same rate or less than the refill rate, you will not get throttling exceptions. If you are making API calls faster than the refill rate, the credit in your bucket will be gradually depleted and you will experience throttled exceptions.

Our setup was an Airflow DAG creating EMR clusters and polling task status on them. Furthermore, we were creating the boto3 client using Airflow's wrapper (AwsBaseHook) so implementing/changing the config to increase retries was not an option.

Solution:

- Manually add retries with backoff around a try-catch block which internally called the polling function.
- Asking the AWS team to increase the rate.
- Using Cloudtrail to find the culprit. [Must do]

Hope this helps!